# Change foreign key using SQL

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sql-update

I have a table like this:

```
ID    Name      Email           Referred_by
-------------------------------------------
1     John      john@foo.com    NULL
2     Sam       sam@foo.com     john@foo.com
3     Sally     sally@foo.com   sam@foo.com
..... more rows .....
```

And I would like to change it to:

```
ID    Name      Email           Referred_by
-------------------------------------------
1     John      john@foo.com    NULL
2     Sam       sam@foo.com     1
3     Sally     sally@foo.com   2
..... more rows .....
```

Can I make this change using SQL?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE my_table a
set    a.referred_by = (
       SELECT b.id
       FROM   my_table b
       WHERE  b.email = a.referred_by
);
```

Comment: I think you have it the other way around.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it once I realised that :)

Comment: And once you do that you should change the datatype to integer so the old values cannot be inserted again.

Comment: mysql gives me: You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause

Comment: You didn't mention MySQL before - it has trouble with subqueries in UPDATE statements, especially if it's a self join. You need to create a temporary copy of the table (using ENGINE=MEMORY) and self join to that, without aliases (i.e. my_table_temp.email = my_table.referred_by).

Answer (score 1):

Many DBMS' will allow this by the use of DDL (definition) statements rather than DML (manipulation). Assuming that `id` is an integral type and `referred_by` is (currently) a textual column, you can do something like:

- alter the table to add a new column `ref2` (nullable) of the same type as `id`.
- set up a foreign key constraint between that `ref2` and `id`.
- populate the `ref2` column for all the rows.
- drop the original constraint.
- alter the table to remove column `referred_by`.
- alter the table to rename column `ref2` to `referred_by`.